# How to use the same itemssource in different methods

Tags: vb.net

I fill a `ListView` in the initialize with data of a db (per LINQ) and use the `ItemsSource` to update the `ListView`. Then I wrote some other methods to filter the `ListView`.

Everything works fine, because I only use one filtermethod at the same time.
Now I want to use two or more methods at the same time on the same `ItemsSource`.

For example:  I want to filter my default list `list1` for a specific **state** (we call the new list now `list2`). Then want to search in that `list2` (with an other filtermethod) every file that is older then a specific **date**. But at the moment I just can filter the **state** OR the **date**.

**Question:** How to use the same `ItemsSource` of my `startList()` in different methods?

```
Sub startList()
    Dim defaultList = From test In container.view_test.Where(Function(v) v.StateID = 1)
    lstvw_Overview.ItemsSource = defaultList.ToList
End Sub
```

Filtermethods:

```
Private Sub chkbx_Unfinished_UnChecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles chkbx_Unfinished.Unchecked
    Try
        Dim uncheckedList = From test In container.view_test
        lstvw_Overview.ItemsSource = uncheckedList.ToList // here
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error at 'unchecking' the checkbox: " + vbNewLine + ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub filternNachUnzustellbarMail()
    Try
        Dim comparestring As String = txtbx_1.Text
        Dim filterUnzustellbarMail = From test In container.view_test
                                     Where test.unzustellbarMail.Contains(comparestring)

        lstvw_Overview.ItemsSource = filterUnzustellbarMail.ToList // here
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error at ... " + vbNewLine + ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. What prevents you from modifying the LINQ query to include multiple filters?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the problem is that i want to modify the ItemsSource in `startLilst()` depending on the filtermethods i use. Atm I just create new ItemsSources in the filtermethods. So i cant `uncheck`and `filternNach...` at the same time.

Comment: why you need startlist at all? Or why you need the other filtermethods at the same time? I think they are triggered from events, why multiple at the same time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i need the startList() because if i start the programm the listview should be filled already. I though it would be more handy to have various filtermethods. f.e. i want to filter my list first for a specific state (we name it now `list2`), then i want to search in that `list2` with an other filtermethod every file that is older then a specific date. But atm i just can filter the state OR the date. Iam sry my english is pretty bad xD

Answer (score 0):

You should try and filter the original datasource(Which you first got from the db) with additional filter everytime. (Where Condition1=value and Condition2=value and then set the datasource of the new list with new results.

```
Dim defaultList = From test In container.view_test.Where(Function(v) v.StateID = 1 and v.date<mydate)
    List2.Overview.ItemsSource = defaultList.ToList
```

Comment: and how do u recommend that I use my defaultlist in other subs? Or do u mean that I should do for every possibility a `IF - Clause` in my `startList()`?